# Instanciar una Clase con namespace tomando el controlador de URL

Tags: php, mvc, php7, namespace

Estoy trabajando con el patrón mvc y estoy usando namespace en php. Y la pregunta es: **¿Cómo puedo instanciar una clase con namespace tomando el valor del controlador desde la URL  sin la necesidad de requerir el archivo?**

```
namespace Libs\App;

use Controllers\Home; # Controlador principar/por defecto
use Controllers\Registro;
use Controllers\Fail; # Controlador de pagina no encontrada

use function class_exists;

class App 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $url = isset($_GET['url'])? $_GET['url']: null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        // Si el controlador en URL está vació, por defecto se instancia el controlador Home
        if (empty($url[0])) {
            $controller = new Home;

            return false;

        } else {

            /*
             * Si se escribe la URL manualmente, por ejmplo, no quiero ir a "home" sino a "registro" y escribo ejemplo.com/registro  
             * me debe instanciar el controlador Registro.
             *
             * La variable $url, esta guardando, en la posición del controlador [0], lo que se le escribe desde el controlador para instanciarlo autmaticamente.
             *
             */
            new $url[0];
        }


    }

}
```

como pueden observar, mientras la url esté vacía, me va a instanciar el contrlador por defecto. Todo bien hasta aquí. **Pero, cuando se escribe una dirección especifica, como por ejemplo: example.com/registro es aquí donde el problema.**

Como pueden observar en el **else,** la URL no está vacía, se le está pasando algo, pero, ese algo que se le pasa, no lo toma en cuenta. Por ejemplo, el valor de la $url debería ser "regirstro" y, automaticamente, debe instanciar el controlador registro. Pero, no lo hace. Me muestra el siguiente Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'registro' not found in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\JhossWeb\php\psr4\libs\App.php:35 Stack trace: #0
> D:\xampp\htdocs\JhossWeb\php\psr4\index.php(7):
> Libs\App\App->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\JhossWeb\php\psr4\libs\App.php on line 35

Ahora, traté de resolver ese problema con un **switch(),** pero, tendría que crear un case por cada "controlador" como lo pueden observar **(No tomar en cuenta, es solo un ejemplo. El código principal, es el de arriba)** :

```
        switch ($url[0]) {
            case 'home':
                
                $controller = new Home;
                $controller->loadModel('home');
                $controller->render();
                break;

            case 'nuevo':
                
                $controller = new Registro;
                $controller->loadModel('registro');
                $controller->render();
                break;
            
            default:
                $controller = new Fail;
                break;
        }
```

Pero, esta solucion me parece poco eficiente porque, a la hora que se agreguen más controladores, se agregaran más "case" y eso es lo que quiero evitar.

Me podrían ayudar? de ante mano, gracias

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún mecanismo autoload? `use Controler\xxxx` requiere de carga previa del archivo contenedor del código de xxxx cuando no hay autoload, en tal caso necesitas un include o requiere explícito para los controladores. Si lo usas revisa el mecanismo de *registro de clases* que emplea para asegurar que sus paths estén presentes

Comment: si, estoy usando el `autoload` de `composer` y, el archivo **composer.json** lo tengo así: "autoload": { "psr-4": { "Libs\\App\\": "libs/", "Controllers\\": "controllers/" } }

Comment: Una nota adicional que acabo de percibir: escribes: `$controller = new Home;` deberías haber escrito: `$controller = new Home();` **no se está creando la instancia de la clase**

Comment: Adicionalmente, en el controller debes tener un mecanismo para resolver parámetros pasados en la construcción de la ruta

Comment: Ok. Me podrías orientar para arreglar lo último que me dices?

Comment: Hola. Con mucho gusto. Pero este no sería el lugar adecuado. Cuando te conectes entra al [Chat de StackOverflow en Español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) yo suelo dejar una pestaña conectada mientras trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($url[0]!='') {
            $name = $url[0];
            $controller = new $name;
            $controller->loadModel($name);
            $controller->render();
 }
```

....debería funcionar... si no, espero captes mi idea

Comment: Amplia tu respuesta para una mejor comprensión. Incluye un ejemplo.

Comment: intente ese manera de resolverlo y nada. me sigue diciendo que la Clase no esta definida, cuando, la estoy importando con el método use al principio del código.

Answer (score 0):

Hola el día de ayer publique una pregunta similar a la tuya, me generaba el mismo error, lo pude solucionar, intenta poner  `$rutaNamespace = 'Controllers\\'.$url[0]` y enseguida vincula tu variables `new $rutaNamespace`. te dejo el ejemplo que realize es de lo más básico pero prueba todo lo que mencionas en tu pregunta. https://github.com/memos1/prueba